# Avoid selectItem change on arrow press

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have changed my WPF Combobox so that when i begin typing it filters the list based on items that CONTAIN the string (opposed to just starting with it). See an example here:

[image]

When i press the down arrow :

[image]

As you can see it IS moving down (because it is selecting the 2nd one on the list). However, once it moves down, then it changes the SelectedItem, which triggers my filtering function. This filters the dropdown list to items that contain the string in the box. Being as there is only one with the matching name, that is now the only choice that the user has.

I need a way to scroll down without changing the SelectedItem, or at least not having that change reflected in the textbox.

Comment: are you trying to accomplish this from a behavior?

Comment: Preferably yes a command or behavior

Comment: you could add a relaycommand with parameter to be called on dropdownClosed and send the current selected item as the parameter. This way you don't need to bind the selectedItem property and you can trigger your filters from the command's execute.       EDIT: i created a sample project and i don't have selection change occurring on arrow key press. maybe you can edit your custom control to handle the keydown? e.handle true on previewkeydown?

Comment: can i see the sample?

Comment: it's just the stock combobox, without search textbox, unlike yours. but with the relaycommand yours should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's is a direct way to do this. The easiest way is to create a class that inherits from the `ComboBox` xaml control, having a new propery called `IsReadOnly` then you can override the `OnPreviewKeyDown` method

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                if (IsReadOnly)
                {
                    if (e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Up)
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                        return; // do not call the base class method OnPreviewKeyDown()
                    }
                }

                base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
            }
```

Comment: this doesnt help, it is still changing the SelectedIndex